# personal ad - schema markup

Tags: markup, microformats, schema.org

We have a website where people can create personal ads in order to find language-partners.

Does anyone have an idea on how to markup these ads using schema.org?

By now we only have rel=author on each author-name of an ad. But it would be good if we could also markup the following elements of the ads:

- the ad itself (the div that wraps the ad)
- author-image
- authoer location/homelocation
- creation date
- mothertongue
- wanted/learn language
- description

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you give an example of the current HTML for one ad?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, not exactly an expert here, but I think you should wrap all that in a `http://schema.org/Person` and use the already existing tags for that, assuming the ad links to a user's homepage you can just add the link as a url for the person.
Assuming a div contains all that you just define it as:

```
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
.... all the properties ....
</div>
```

If I'm not mistaken all the described properties are already defined in Person, in fact you can find most of them in the example at the bottom of the page, just take a look at http://schema.org/Person

Really can't give you any more information without an already existing markup sample.